# Whats better for 2H Vet. Solo Eng.- Vit or Dex?

Tags: torchlight-2

So I'm playing a 2h engineer solo on veteran difficulty and i want to know opinions on what would be better to put points in to- vit and str, or dex and str? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The current best knowledge on the Runic forums is that vitality is only good for adding block to shields.  The other things that vitality adds are HP and % bonus to armor.  Both of those are useful but neither are cost-effective to obtain from vitality.  You can easily get +HP gems that give you hundreds of vitality worth of extra HP.  The way the game is balanced, beginning NG+ and into the late game, enemy damage scales up rapidly, far outpacing the amount of armor you will be able to get.  This tends to make damage reduction and extra HP far more useful than armor.  In fact, the later in the game you are, the more useless flat armor tends to become.

In summary, most of your points should be going into strength.  Since you are using two-handed weapons, you will not have a shield, so vitality points would not be very helpful.  You can throw a few into dex for both dodge and crit chance, but not too much.  In Torchlight 2, the best defense is killing the mobs before they get a chance to land that one-hit-KO on you.

Comment: Strenght doesn't really increases the damage by so much that he should put most of his points there. The stat increases from all attributes are quite low, and if you ask me you should level the attributes mainly for gear requirements. So vitality for better armors, strenght for better weapons, unless you are using ranged weapon in which case you'll need dexterity and of course focus if you're embermage.

Comment: Dexterity does not help ranged weapons at all.  This is not Torchlight 1.  All weapon damage comes from strength.  Dex is for dodge, crit chance, and fumble reduction.  Strength adds 0.5% weapon damage per point.  If you put 400 points in Str that is 200% bonus weapon damage.  Considering how most Engineer skills use weapon DPS for base damage, that is also a huge boost to skill damage as well.  I already explained why vitality for armor is a huge waste of stat points.

Comment: Using gear requirements to pick your stat allocation is a great way to screw up a character. A lot of gear has requirements that don't make much sense at all, and most of the stuff you find by yourself is not that good anyways. It's almost never worth wasting stat points for gear, if your goal is to play to level 100 beyond NG+, since when you get high level you will be able to equip everything anyways.

Comment: Here's the formulas for the stats, by the way: [stat gain details](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=53244&hilit=stat+formulas).